# Using an image as a CellDingbat

Tags: notebooks, cells, stylesheet

I'm writing code that generates a report notebook using a defined style. I would like to display an image (a logo) in the title cell along with the title itself. How can this be done?

Example:

```
CreateDocument[
{
TextCell["Results Summary", "Title"],
TextCell["Some test", "Text"],
TextCell["This is a test", "Subtitle"],
TextCell["First section", "Section"]
},
StyleDefinitions -> Notebook@
 {
 Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
 Cell[StyleData["Title"], FontColor -> Blue, 
  CellDingbat -> {Cell[GraphicsData[img]]}],
 Cell[StyleData["Section"], FontColor -> Green, 
  CellDingbat -> {Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Section"]}]]}],
 Cell[StyleData["Subsection"], FontColor -> Red, 
  CellDingbat -> {Cell[
     TextData[{CounterBox["Section"], ".", 
       CounterBox["Subsection"]}]]
    }
  ]
 }
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating the [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) expression using [`ToBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToBoxes). First an example image:

```
image = Thumbnail[
    ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}],
    30
]
```

> [image]

Then, use `BoxData @ ToBoxes @ image` to create the cell:

```
CreateDocument[
    {
    TextCell["Results Summary", "Title"],
    TextCell["Some test", "Text"],
    TextCell["This is a test", "Subtitle"],
    TextCell["First section", "Section"]
    },
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook@
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Title"],
            FontColor -> Blue, 
            CellDingbat -> {Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes @ image]}
        ],
        Cell[StyleData["Section"],
            FontColor -> Green, 
            CellDingbat -> {Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Section"]}]]}
        ],
        Cell[StyleData["Subsection"],
            FontColor -> Red, 
            CellDingbat -> 
            {
            Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Section"], ".", CounterBox["Subsection"]}]]
            }
        ]
        }
];
```